# Compatibility issue for mongoDB 3.6 to add Validator

Tags: mongodb

```js
{   "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "The featureCompatibilityVersion must be 3.6 to create a collection validator using 3.6 query features. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.6-feature-compatibility.",
    "code" : 224,
    "codeName" : "QueryFeatureNotAllowed"
}
```

The Above is the error in MongoDB.

Version - 3.6.2;
OS: Ubuntu 16.0.4;

Comment: did you checkout the link from the error message?

Comment: Thaks @ztadic91 for trying to solve the question. I have  given the Solution in the Thread below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you guys for trying to answer my question but I solved the issue myself.

For me the solution was to execute the following command:

```js
db.adminCommand({setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6"})
```